# Samsung Galaxy A7 (2017) Emulation In Google Chrome Devtools

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to define a custom setting for my Samsung Galaxy A7 (2017) in Google Chrome devtools as described in the following article: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/emulate-mobile-viewports.
According to device's specs, it's resolution is 1080 x 1920 pixels, but unfortunately is doesn't makes sense when I'm using it because the screen looks extremely big.
What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I once experienced it, I used xiaomi but I tried to restart google chrome and tried it back It's work for me!